# Code creating two json elements when should be just the one

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a json encode using the following code but it's inlcuding the full json as two seperate items the second json entity needs to be included with the properties.

// we just want to use simple php json encode here no need to over complicated.

```
public function generate_json($table_data) {
    $result=array();
    $result[]=$table_data;

    if ($table_data) {            
       $result[]= $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data(20);
    }

    return json_encode($result);
}


public function get_table_data() {
    $where = $this->get_query_where();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__{$this->export_table}` WHERE 1 " . $where;
    return wpl_db::select($query, 'loadAssocList');
}

public function get_property_gallery_data($property_id) {
    $items_table="wpl_items";
    $where = $this->get_query_where();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__wpl_items`  WHERE 1 " .$where.' and parent_id='.$property_id;           

    return wpl_db::select($query, 'loadAssocList'); 
}
```

If you paste the below json into a viewer you can get an example

Comment: what is the actual result, what is the expected result?

Comment: two json elements instead of the one combined json elements i s the gallery items are  being correct in a sperate {} as should be along wit the propertys in one {}

Comment: please add in your question the precise JSON you get, and the precise JSON you wish...

Comment: @Random Its sesitive data so i am not allowed to sorry

Comment: you can change text... we just need the structure...

Comment: As far as I see, you need to change `$result[] = ` -> `$result = ` (to set one array result and not both)

Answer (score 0):

There are two $result arrays.
Use `array_push` to push results in single array and then encode it with json

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Below code will do the trick

```
<?PHP
    public function generate_json($table_data) {
        $result=array();
        $result1[]=$table_data;

        if ($table_data) {            
           $result2[]= $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data(20);
        }
        $result[] = array_merge($result1,$result2);
        return json_encode($result);
    }


    public function get_table_data() {
        $where = $this->get_query_where();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__{$this->export_table}` WHERE 1 " . $where;
        return wpl_db::select($query, 'loadAssocList');
    }

    public function get_property_gallery_data($property_id) {
        $items_table="wpl_items";
        $where = $this->get_query_where();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__wpl_items`  WHERE 1 " .$where.' and parent_id='.$property_id;           

        return wpl_db::select($query, 'loadAssocList'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: afraid not its still producing two elements

Comment: I have checked it is giving only one json..Please check again